# how to import the correct module where the name exists multiple times in site-packages

Tags: python

I am trying to import mpi4py on a distributed computing system.  However there are two modules by that name in my site-package directory.

site-package/

- mpi4py
- mpich2/mpi4py

It's the mpich2 version of mpi4py module that I want to import; however, I am only able to import the other version.

I have tried adding `/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/mpich2/mpi4py` to `PYTHONPATH` and I have tried `sys.path.append('/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/mpich2/mpi4py')`. However, I end up with the non mpich2 version of mpi4py each time.

I have also tried `import mpich2.mpi4py`, but that doesn't work.

Any thoughts/suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Where are you executing the program from? Perhaps *in python code* try explicitly setting the current working directory to the "site-package" directory, directly before `import mpich2.mpi4py`

Comment: try `sys.path.insert(0, ...)` - appending to the end means that the existing paths are still searched first.

Comment: Is mpich2 a python package (does it have an __init__.py)? Do you know where it came from?

Comment: sys.path.insert(0, ...) does the job.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the directory at the start of `sys.path`:

```
sys.path[0:0] = ['/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/mpich2']
import mpi4py
```